# Dart Polymer @observable variable initialization handling in polymer 0.10.0

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have run across a strange behaviour after upgrading from polymer 0.9.5 to 0.10.0+1.

I have 2 elements, parent and child.
Parent defines a @observable variable.

If I initialize this variable at declaration site and in created(), the app never launches.
Is that expected?

```dart
@CustomTag('parent-elem')
class ParentElem extends PolymerElement {
  //@observable String myValue1 = "Init value";  //Fails
  @observable String myValue1;  //works fine

  ParentElem.created() : super.created() {
    myValue1 = "Hello world";
  }
}
```

This is used by a child Element:

```dart
@CustomTag('second-elem')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  @published String myValue2;

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created() {
  }

}
```

And bound via:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="secondelem.html">
<polymer-element name="parent-elem">
  <template>    
    <div>
      <h1>Parent elem</h1>      
      <span>(my value: {{myValue1}})</span>
    </div>
     <second-elem myValue2="{{myValue1}}"></second-elem> 
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="parent_elem.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Have you updated how polymer is initialized (for example in index.html) for 0.10.0?

Comment: yep, I added <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html"> at the top of the head

Comment: I think you should just file a bug at dartbug.com/new.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19467